# MySQL : only_full_group_by multiple date isn't in group by

Tags: mysql, group-by

How is the correct query when only_full_group_by activated?

```
SELECT
    MAX(DATE (`date`)) AS `date_full`,
    WEEKDAY(`date`) AS `date_week`,
    COUNT(`id`) AS `visits`
    FROM `xxx_visits_stats` 
    WHERE YEAR(`date`) = YEAR("2017-01-01") 
    GROUP BY `date_week`
    ORDER BY `date` DESC
```

Without(disabled) only_full_group_by it works!

Comment: Why wouldn't it work?

Comment: MySQL Error: 'xxx_visits_stats.date' isn't in GROUP BY.  When i use DATE in group by the query will not be correct

Comment: don't see anything wrong...

Comment: `xxx_visits_stats` is table name and not column name. you sure that's the error

Comment: Yes it is correct table name.

Comment: So GROUP BY ``WEEKDAY(date)`doesn't work either?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is due to the fact that you're ordering by a column that's not mentioned in the GROUP BY and also not an aggregate.

Try this:

```
  SELECT MAX(DATE(`date`)) AS `date_full`,
         WEEKDAY(`date`) AS `date_week`,
         COUNT(`id`) AS `visits`
    FROM `xxx_visits_stats` 
   WHERE YEAR(`date`) = YEAR("2017-01-01") 
   GROUP BY WEEKDAY(`date`)
   ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

That form of `ORDER BY` means use the first column in the SELECT clause for ordering.

Comment: Thanks, that's it. "That form of ORDER BY means use the first column in the SELECT clause for ordering."